# Instagram API returns a code, but when requesting an access token says the same code is invalid

Tags: android, ruby, oauth, instagram

Using the Instagram rubygem and sinatra I am able to successfully authenticate via oauth from a small AngularJS app and use the Instagram API. Here are the relevant oauth routes from my sinatra app:

```
get '/oauth/connect' do
    logger.info "going here " + (Instagram.authorize_url :redirect_uri => CALLBACK)
    redirect Instagram.authorize_url :redirect_uri => CALLBACK
end

get "/oauth/callback" do
    logger.info params[:code]
    response = Instagram.get_access_token params[:code], :redirect_uri => CALLBACK
    session[:access_token] = response.access_token

    users = DB[:users]
    current_user = users[:instagram_id => response.user.id.to_i]

    if current_user.nil?
        new_user = response.user
        users.insert :instagram_id => new_user.id.to_i, 
                             :username => new_user.username, 
                             :profile_picture => new_user.profile_picture,
                             :created_at => DateTime.now

        current_user = users[:instagram_id => new_user.id]
    end
    session[:current_user] = current_user
    redirect "/app"
end
```

However, when trying to authenticate from within a webview in an Android app using the same routes (GET oauth/connect, redirected to Instagram, then redirected back to oauth/callback) I get the following error:

```
Instagram::BadRequest - POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/: 400: OAuthException: No matching code found.:
```

I have verified that I am using the same code returned from Instagram and that the redirect_uri is the same as what I registered with Instagram.

Note, Oauth works when I use my web interface, but not via the Android webview.

I have read a number of posts where other people have seen this behavior, but the solutions provided do not work for me:

1. Instagram can disable your app because it thinks it is misbehaving. Nope, because oauth works via my web-interface still using the same client ID and secret and the same routes.
2. You are not using the same redirect_uri as that listed with Instagram. I have checked and re-checked this and it looks fine.

Where can I debug next to get to the bottom of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know my answer is a bit late, but I'm posting it here so others (hopefully) won't have to search as hard as I did.

It looks like you're using the Explicit auth.  We were having this issue using the explicit flow.

Here's the problem:  In the instant after you send the code to Instagram (step 3), that code expires.  However, Instagram will not send you a new code (step 1 & 2) for at least 5 minutes (it re-issues the old code).

Make certain that you aren't sending more than one request with the same code (Android WebView tends to arbitrarily send multiple requests).  Or, better yet, cache the code->Instagram_response mapping on the server.

Comment: Yep, the Android WebView onPageFinished callback was firing twice and I was initiating two auth calls.

Comment: Please look into this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052304/oauthaccesstokenexception-the-access-token-provided-is-invalid-instagram-new-api?noredirect=1#comment104600245_59052304

Comment: @user2028, sorry, I haven't touched the Instagram API in almost 5 years.