# OAuthAccessTokenException-The access_token provided is invalid Instagram new api

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am integrating Instagram login into my application. As per the provided documentation in bellow link: 
https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

For getting CODE I hit follow API:

**`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?app_id="your app_id"&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com/&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code`**

After hitting above API in web-view I got bellow new URL with code in it:

```
http://www.google.com/?code=AQCPw4m0jd85IX7Qi83rd-pxsFKDE8Bjb0kZ2pWZ8sarcPlNyaZXwzE1yHHqfVIgDej_ZPYrTh6_BaIafsOWsTZNJbWFDiXsQPTEZHvFBojQ5F91SBSykqjUkG0U1OS6nFyAcwNq-FsbpmBtIPcp45qNXV5_avgCCpBzG-Hndp6JiRbaF2uSgUiOep5-Uu0Ks8DiwVs_7zAfuMasJJ7PAK1gfRDNVOPC-XBYqfdPU1VlkA
```

In this example my code is

> AQCPw4m0jd85IX7Qi83rd-pxsFKDE8Bjb0kZ2pWZ8sarcPlNyaZXwzE1yHHqfVIgDej_ZPYrTh6_BaIafsOWsTZNJbWFDiXsQPTEZHvFBojQ5F91SBSykqjUkG0U1OS6nFyAcwNq-FsbpmBtIPcp45qNXV5_avgCCpBzG-Hndp6JiRbaF2uSgUiOep5-Uu0Ks8DiwVs_7zAfuMasJJ7PAK1gfRDNVOPC-XBYqfdPU1VlkA

I use it in access_token request below:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?
app_id="YOUR APP ID"
&app_secret="YOUR SECRET KEY"
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F
&code=AQCPw4m0jd85IX7Qi83rd-pxsFKDE8Bjb0kZ2pWZ8sarcPlNyaZXwzE1yHHqfVIgDej_ZPYrTh6_BaIafsOWsTZNJbWFDiXsQPTEZHvFBojQ5F91SBSykqjUkG0U1OS6nFyAcwNq-FsbpmBtIPcp45qNXV5_avgCCpBzG-Hndp6JiRbaF2uSgUiOep5-Uu0Ks8DiwVs_7zAfuMasJJ7PAK1gfRDNVOPC-XBYqfdPU1VlkA
```

Response of above api hit:

```
{
    "access_token": "IGQVJVT2hod1dEN3N0UnBwTWllb3pZAaENnS0VveHZARSkNwLVpwS2Uxc0w2VUVOeEJxaUdkMnlQRkdzVGJudnh0cXREZA3BvWHNELTR1UndsOWR2MXFST0JlUG45TEdFVnhiblhScVNlYlJtLUNwQU5Kc2ltZAy1LUlRMaF9ZA",
    "user_id": 17841406439718884
}
```

Now in order to get User Profile data, I am hitting bellow api using above access_token as mentioned in [link][1] :

Api hit :

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token="+accesstoken

But in this api, I am getting error which says:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 400,
        "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException",
        "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to get valid accessToken programmatically , I have clearly mentioned every step I follow if you stil need anything for more calrification I willprovide you that too!!!

**I have followed each and every step mentioed in this link** :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions

Comment: You are using an access token for the old API, with the new basic display API. That won't work. For the old API, tokens seem to expire randomly, so no way to get a permanent or long-lived token. For the new Basic Display API, the tokens expire after 2 hours.

Comment: Stop using Instagram APIs for self details. Use Facebook Graph API. Instagram APIs are all deprecated. It will stop completely in Early 2020. Refer  https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: @hermanschutte Are you able to get the acess_token ? I always get a message saying "code doesn't exist or is already used"

Comment: @ShaharyarKirmani, Provide secure redirect URL in the developer console.

Comment: Are you sure that the Instagram app installed in your device is the latest one?

Comment: @hermanschutte i am using https still getting the same error, been stuck on this for days now.

Comment: @ShaharyarKirmani try to generate secure URL from ngrok php

Comment: @hermanschutte Can't it be a simple secure URL of my hosting ? Is that different ?

Comment: @ShaharyarKirmani try dropping the last 2 characters from the code you're using, so don't include the `#_`

Comment: @hermanschutte did that already still same error code. Really strange.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526137/my-app-was-rejected-by-instagram-basic-display-api-review-due-to-invalid-reasons

Comment: @AmrutBidri, for getting CODE, does one need to login for that? Because it askes me to login.

Comment: @user2028, do I need to login to get  the CODE?

Comment: yes. You must login first to get the CODE.

Comment: @user2028 did you manage to fix this - any chance you can post the full solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is very poorly documented by Facebook and they made it very difficult. I will go through the steps so that you do not suffer as much I suffered...

```js
{
    "access_token": "IGQVJVT2hod1dEN3N0UnBwTWllb3pZAaENnS0VveHZARSkNwLVpwS2Uxc0w2VUVOeEJxaUdkMnlQRkdzVGJudnh0cXREZA3BvWHNELTR1UndsOWR2MXFST0JlUG45TEdFVnhiblhScVNlYlJtLUNwQU5Kc2ltZAy1LUlRMaF9ZA",
    "user_id": 17841406439718884
}
```

This is a short-lived token which expires in 1 hour; therefore you should use that to generate a long-lived token. before it expires: To do so used that piece link in postman

```js
 "https://graph.instagram.com/access_token
  ?grant_type=ig_exchange_token
  &client_secret={instagram-app-secret}
  &access_token={short-lived-access-token}"
```

Then you will get as a response

```js
{
  "access_token":"{long-lived-user-access-token}",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 5183944  // Number of seconds until token expires
}
```

This is your long term access token and it shows the expiration date which 60 days.
Then you should use the request lin

```js
GET https://graph.instagram.com/{media-id}
  ?fields=id,caption,username,
  &access_token={access-token}// Long Lived token
```

See their website for more data query: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user#fields

I hope that helps you to solve the problem. I am writing a piece code to refresh the long-lived token before its expiration in 60 days. Once I finish it I will share that as well

Comment: This should work as Token extender: https://graph.instagram.com/refresh_access_token?grant_type=ig_refresh_token&access_token={YOUR_LONG_LIVE_TOKEN}

But I always get: "Invalid OAuth access token"

Why? I use a token which is working in production.